# Jar file throws an exception

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I use java 1.8 and IntelliJIdea. To use the program, I download the font

```
InputStream is1 = GameField.class.getResourceAsStream("assets/fonts/ARIALN.ttf");
private Font myArialNarrow;
    {
        try {
            myArialNarrow = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is1);
        } catch (FontFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("error1");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("error2");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
private Font myFont1 = myArialNarrow.deriveFont(30f);
```

As a result, I have a font myFont1 with a size of 30. When I run the program in the IDE, everything works fine, but if I do a jar the file throws an exception:

```
error2
java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
at java.awt.Font.createFont0(Font.java:1000)
at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:877)
at com.pumaex.GameField.<init>(GameField.java:57)
at com.pumaex.LinesLauncher.main(LinesLauncher.java:5)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.pumaex.GameField.<init>(GameField.java:70)
at com.pumaex.LinesLauncher.main(LinesLauncher.java:5)
```

Why can't the program find the font file? Am I writing the wrong path? Tell me, what is the mistake?

added

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Problem {

    public static Font loadFile(String filePath) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, FontFormatException {
        try (final InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(Problem.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath))) {
            return Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Font font = loadFile("assets/fonts/ARIALN.ttf");
        Font myFont1 = font.deriveFont(30f);
        System.out.println(myFont1);
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) Instead of going direct to an input stream, try this simple bit of debug code: `URL url = GameField.class.getResource("assets/fonts/ARIALN.ttf"); System.out.println("URL: url);` 2) Note that the form of using `getResource..` looks suspiciously like it would be getting the bootstrap class loader rather then the one intended for application resources, but first report back the result of point (1).

Comment: Inserted row: URL url = GameField.class.getResource("assets/fonts/ARIALN.ttf"); System.out.println("URL:"+ url); Got in the console - URL:file:/C:/Users/Ura/IdeaProjects/Lines1/out/production/Lines1/com/pumaex/assets/fonts/ARIALN.ttf

Comment: Huh .. OK I'm slightly surprised it returned a valid URL. So onto the next thing. Create a **buffered** input stream based on that URL and pass that stream to the `createFont` method.

Comment: in the question I added. (See the program in question). I am running this program. Everything is working fine. But if I make a jar-file and run it, I get an exception:  Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Comment: I don’t understand anything at all. What is the mistake?

Comment: *"What is the mistake?"* Until I see the code that shows creating a buffered input stream, I'm not spending further time on this.